# Impact of a falling object on the surface

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, collision

Suppose an object of 75 kg falls from a height of 2 feet on land. Normally the land will feel the weight on it as 75 kg. But when the object is fallen from a height it will have some speed so at the point of contact what will be the exact or approximate weight that the land will feel?

Comment: You could plot the magnitude of the force between the object and the ground as a function of time. It would start at zero, it would quickly go up to some value greater than 75kg, and then it would settle at 75kg. Predicting the exact shape of that plot (including finding the max value) would require a lot of detailed information about the structure of the "object" and the materials from which it was made, and similar information about the "ground" upon which it lands. Maybe have to run some [finite element analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_element_method) to get the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The impact force will be greater than the weight and will depend on the stopping distance when it hits the ground. From the work energy theorem

$$Fd=\frac {mv^2}{2}$$

Where $F$ is the average impact force, $d$ is the stopping distance and $v$ is the velocity at impact. This assumes the loss of potential energy over the stopping distance is negligible compared to the kinetic at impact.

Once the object stops the force on the ground will equal the weight.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When the object is falling it gains more and more kinetic energy and when it hits the ground it turns most of the kinetic energy into potential while it changes it momentum. The change in momentum causes an impulsive force to act on the ground as, F = M ∆v/∆t. And if there is no bounce back taking place then this impulsive force, which acts from the moment it touches the floor to the moment it's velocity becomes 0, becomes huge.

Comment: Upon impact, the kinetic energy is lost to heat and friction in the ground - none of it gets stored as useful potential energy. In an inelastic collision like this, all of the kinetic energy is simply dissipated, and is not conserved.

Comment: @NuclearWang Some of the energy is indeed stored as potential energy of soil particles or grass as spring-like systems. Remove the object pushing the soil or grass, they will flex back toward a non-compressed position. Depending on the purpose of the soil or grass (golf courses?) the compression or release of compression could be useful. Small effect by pedestrian standards, but not unimportant.

Comment: @NuclearWang Seems to me whether the energy lost by the falling object gets stored as potential energy in the ground or dissipated as heat in the ground is irrelevant as far as the average impact force is concerned.